# TypeScript cannot find module if it contains a require

Tags: typescript, typescript1.8

I'm trying to understand how to properly work with TypeScript and classic JS node modules.

I set up a very basic project, with the following file architecture:

```
.
├── index.ts
├── lodash.d.ts
├── module.ts
└── node_modules
    └── lodash
```

`lodash` has been installed with `npm`. As it seems to provide no typings info, I wrote a basic `d.ts` file that only describes one function, just to please `tsc` and avoid error about not knowing `lodash`.

**lodash.d.ts**

```
declare module "lodash" {
  export function reverse(array: any[]): any[];
}
```

In my `module.ts` file, I import lodash with `require` and expose a function on a module, which I use on `index.ts` file.

**module.ts**

```
/// <reference path="./lodash.d.ts" />

import _ = require('lodash');

module FooModule {
  export function foo() {
    return _.reverse([1, 2, 3]);
  }
}
```

**index.ts**

```
/// <reference path="./module.ts" />

let a = FooModule.foo();
console.log(a);
```

The problem is that `tsc` (and so VS Code) tells me that it can't find name `FooModule`.

```
$ tsc index.ts --module commonjs -outDir build
index.ts(3,9): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'FooModule'.
```

However, if I remove the `import _ = require('lodash');` from `module.ts`, it works correctly (except the obvious fact that `_` variable is now undefined).

Am I doing something wrong with this `require`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are mixing internal modules and external modules. If you use a top-level import or export statement in a `.ts` file, the file *itself* is automatically considered as an external module, its contents all part of that module (`require` is an import statement).

If you put an internal module inside an external module (`module` or `namespace` keyword), you are effectively double-wrapping your module contents. That is not good.

Take the following example:

**module.ts**

```
import _ = require('lodash');

module FooModule {
    export function foo() {
        return _.reverse([1, 2, 3]);
    }
}
```

Function `foo` is now effectively `module.FooModule.foo` if you export the internal module `FooModule` from external module `module`:

```
export module FooModule {
    // ...
}
```

However, this is *bad*.

Comment: I get it, thanks for the clear explanation. But if exporting `FooModule` like you suggested at the end of your answer is bad practice, what is the clean way to do it? Or if it's a more architectural problem, how should I do to consume node modules on parts of code I want to expose on my project?

Comment: @Blackus Just remove the `module FooModule` part, and leave your functions in the open. They will be part of module `module` (or whatever your file is named, without the `.ts` extension). Also, don't forget that you'll need a module loading system at runtime (Node.js has built-in).

Comment: I finally understood it, it just works like CommonJS modules (in this case). What actually fooled me a lot in the first place was my way of building (I use webpack with my real project) that was not correct, and all of my files were not correctly rebuilt. It's all clear now. Thanks again :)